# Python 2.5.... MatPlotLib doesn't install PyLab

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, python-2.5

I have NumPy and SciPy installed and working. I'm using Python 2.5 (MIT Intro to Programming course) so I've been installing the packages with .exe files instead of Pip or Anaconda. With MatPlotLib, I get the following errors during installation:

```
could not create: matplotlib-py2.5
could not create: python 2.5 matplotlib-1.0.0 
could not set key value: "C:\Python25\Removematplotlib.exe" -u "C:\Python25\matplotlib-wininst.log"
```

I have a MatPlotLib folder in Python's Lib/site-packages directory. Importing matplotlib into IDLE works fine. But when I try to import pylab:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pylab
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 216, in <module>
    from matplotlib import mpl  # pulls in most modules
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import artist
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 6, in <module>
    from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, TransformedPath
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 34, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import affine_transform
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've looked around on different message boards but can't find anyone else with this issue. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Broken package maybe? Try installing from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib
Also, Python 2.5 is obsolete and unsupported. Consider using Python 2.7, it is backward compatible.

Comment: mpl 1.0.0 is not supported any more either. The error you have comes from the compiled c-extensions not being installed or being complied against the wrong versions windows/compilers/stuff.